# Inability to delete file that was opened (and closed?) using 'with'

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

How this file can be closed. Any idea?

```
 with open('output.txt','w', encoding='UTF-8') as output:
       output.writelines(str(i)+'\n' for i in range(5))
```

Comment: What makes you think it does not get closed?

Comment: I know that must be closed but when i try to delete it give a message it is open in pythonw.exe

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575081/why-doesnt-python-release-file-handles-after-calling-file-close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is automatically closed when you leave the "`with`-block" or an exception is encountered. This is why it's the preferred way to open files.

See this [PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for more information on the `with` statement. [The Python “with” Statement by Example](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) gives more information.

UPDATE:

Your inability to delete a file opened with `with` was due to the file having been left open previously (when not using `with` and not explicitly `close`ing it). As a test using a different file and `with` didn't create a problem.

Comment: Yes but when i go to delete it, give me a message that it is still open in pythonw.exe

Comment: @indiag That should not happen .. perhaps the file is still open from a previous run when you didn't use `with` (I think I saw an earlier question from you, perhaps I'm wrong). It's hard to tell without seeing all of your code. In the meantime, I'd suggest using a different output file name e.g., `output2.txt` and see if you have the same problem just to help troubleshoot/pinpoint the issue.

Comment: How correct are you. Sorry for my mistake. I try 1 hour to understand. ohhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm happy to correct any error or improve the answer if I'm given some constructive feedback. Downvote **without** an explanation doesn't help OP, SO or me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the title did not fit the question, which was anyhow badly worded.  Edit: I'm commenting on the downvote of the question, not the post given by @Levon

Comment: @cdarke I think your comment should be directed at OP not me? I am trying to figure out why I got a downvote for my answer.

Comment: @cdarke Based on your comment I did edit OP's question title to reflect the true nature of the problem (though it's not reasonable to downvote me for OP's choice of words - if that was the reason - which is unknown)

Answer (score 3):

http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

To paraphrase:

In Python 2.5, the file object has been equipped with **enter** and **exit** methods; the former simply returns the file object itself, and the latter closes the file.

So the with statement's "teardown" action is to actually close the file automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`with` statement automatically closes file for you.

read more here: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example